# Why does Telerik ORM increase the value of an SQL Server database column by 10?

Tags: c#, sql-server, orm, telerik, telerik-open-access

I'm working on an SQL Server database where one of my tables has a column whose value seem to be increased by 10 at a time.

The column (called `Customer.Object_id`) is a primary key (as can be seen in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio), but I don't believe that the increase by 10 is handled by SQL Server because, when I use the "Edit" functionality for creating a new tuple, I get the request to fill in that particular column, so it should be handled by something else.

Here is the definition in SQL Server:

[image: SQL-Server definition screenshot]

As an ORM, I use Telerik, so I guess that this one should be responsible, but I don't see it. The mapping configuration looks as follows:

```
private MappingConfiguration<CustomerObj> CreateCustomerObjMapping()
{
    var mapping = new MappingConfiguration<CustomerObj>();
    mapping.FieldNamingRules.CaseMode = Telerik.OpenAccess.Metadata.CaseChangeModes.CamelCase;
    mapping.FieldNamingRules.AddPrefix = "_";
    mapping.MapType(o => new
    {
        o.Id,
        o.Name,
        o.BackgroundColor,
        // o.Code,
        o.ForegroundColor
    }).Inheritance(InheritanceStrategy.Vertical).ToTable(new TableName("Customer.Obj", string.Empty));

    mapping.HasDiscriminatorValue(typeof(CustomerObj).FullName);

    return mapping;
}
```

In here, I don't see any reference to the increase by 10, but I also have no idea how to interpret this information.

The column `Id` is a normal column (although this one should be the one, being handled for this - that's a strategic mistake, done by my predecessor which I can't change any more).

Does anybody have an idea where the increase by 10 in the `Customer.Object_id` column is handled?

Comment: Does the amount of increase correlate to the `Numeric precision` property by any chance? Because that is "10" ... can you set it to - let's say - 5 and test in your dev-environment?

Comment: @Fildor: I saw that too, but the description of that field makes me believe that's not it (or am I mistaking?).

Comment: @Fildor: in the meantime I've found some other tables with a primary key, having 10 as "Number precision" parameter, but the increase is done one by one, so that's not it.

Comment: Ok, too bad. Then that's just coincidence. I am not familiar with telerik, though. So, I am not of use here unfortunately outside upvoting. Good luck.

Comment: It must be in the Telerik logic. That column is not an identity. That means for every new row a value must be provided.

Comment: @SeanLange: indeed. But the value, which seems to be generated automatically, seems equal to the `last_value + 10`, and I'm wondering why 10? (I would like to alter that value into 1)

Comment: I understand what you are saying but why does it matter? Does the value have any significance on your application? If so I might argue you don't want that as the primary key here seems to be an arbitrary value.

Comment: Why not just debug the thing and see what happens?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like Telerik may have opted to use its [HighLow](https://docs.telerik.com/data-access/developers-guide/code-only-mapping/mapping-clr-types-properties-and-associations/defining-identity/fluent-mapping-mapping-clr-defining-identity-single) key generation mechanism for your entity.

> **HighLow** - Telerik Data Access always needs to associate its persistent types with a primary key. If such is not supplied, Telerik Data Access uses internal mechanism for creating IDs.

The HighLow generator has a default **GrabSize** of **10**. This is supposedly [configurable](https://docs.telerik.com/data-access/deprecated/feature-reference/api/context-api/backend-configuration/feature-ref-api-context-api-backend-config-highlow-config) via either code or config.

I don't currently have access to test it -and since the product is deprecated the doc is pretty much stale- but I suspect if you insert more than 1 objects at once *in a single transaction* they may actually have consecutive Ids. (then skipping to the next 10 for the following transaction)